# Symfony 5 Firewalls: Only allow anonymous access

Tags: symfony5, symfony-security

For a Symfony 5 json API, I want to prevent already authenticated users (who have a JWT) from accessing endpoints which should only be accessible to anonymous users i.e. /login or /register.

It seems simple to configure the inverse of that but not to only allow anonymous users.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check which instance of your User is or which ROLES your user has.

edit: Link found
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#checking-to-see-if-a-user-is-logged-in-is-authenticated-fully

```
IS_ANONYMOUS: Only anonymous users are matched by this attribute.
```

Answer (score 0):

in Symfony 6 "IS_ANONYMOUS" was removed, i only found this alternative

```
if ($this->security->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
    return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
}
```

Comment: This does not answer directly the question as the version in the question is 5.